# Conditional rendering in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, rendering, page-refresh

Hello I have this code to conditionally render components in my page:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{Bean.method()}"  value="Submit">
   <f:ajax execute="something" render="one two" />
</h:commandButton>

<p><h:outputFormat rendered="#{Bean.answer=='one'}" id="one" value="#{messages.one}"/></p>
<p><h:outputFormat rendered="#{Bean.answer=='two'}" id="two" value="#{messages.two}"/></p>
```

It gets the answer and renders the component but in order to see it on my page, I need to refresh the page. How can I fix this problem? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 19):

The JSF component's `rendered` attribute is a server-side setting which controls whether JSF should generate the desired HTML or not.

The `<f:ajax>` tag's `render` attribute should point to a (relative) client ID of the JSF-generated HTML element which JavaScript can grab by `document.getElementById()` from HTML DOM tree in order to replace its contents on complete of the ajax request.

However, since you're specifying the client ID of a HTML element which is never rendered by JSF (due to `rendered` being `false`), JavaScript can't find it in the HTML DOM tree.

You need to wrap it in a container component which is *always* rendered and thus *always* available in the HTML DOM tree.

```
<h:commandButton action="#{Bean.method()}"  value="Submit">
   <f:ajax execute="something" render="messages" />
</h:commandButton>

<p>
    <h:panelGroup id="messages">
        <h:outputFormat rendered="#{Bean.answer=='one'}" value="#{messages.one}"/>
        <h:outputFormat rendered="#{Bean.answer=='two'}" value="#{messages.two}"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
</p>
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you've there a possible design mistake. Why would you not just create a `#{Bean.message}` property which you set with the desired message in the action method instead, so that you can just use:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{Bean.method()}"  value="Submit">
   <f:ajax execute="something" render="message" />
</h:commandButton>

<p>
    <h:outputFormat id="message" value="#{Bean.message}" />
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. What I've done is that I used render="@form" in my form and it worked. I will try though what you suggested as well.

Comment: That will indeed also work, as long as it's the component's parent which is *always* rendered (exactly as my answer is trying to tell you). There's maybe only an unnecessary overhead if the form contains 10 other components which doesn't need to be updated at all, for example.

Comment: can we add condition in ajax render?

Answer (score 4):

I know it's not the central point of the question, but as I had this problem many times in the past, I just post it here to help others who are in need.
For those who uses PrimeFaces there's a component in PrimeFaces Extension called [Switch](http://primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/utils/switch.jsf).

> Sometimes you need to display different outputs or components depending on a value. Usually you can achieve this by using the `ui:fragment` tag. With the `pe:switch` util tag you won't have to declare `ui:fragment` tags, with different checks like `ui:fragment rendered="#{!empty someController.value}"`, anymore.

Answer (score -1):

```
style="visibility: #{questionchoose.show==false ? 'hidden' : 'visible'}"
```

Comment: It's better not render the item at all, rather than just not display it.