# how to compare property of columns in datatable primefaces

Tags: primefaces, datatable, multiple-columns

i'm using datatable primefaces with columns. example

```
index----name----status
1        a       0
2        b       1
```

i want to compare, if value of column status will show simple `0=active` and `1=hidden`.
i tried

```
<c:choose>
   <c:if test="#{column.property == 'status'}">
      //i will do something, show value,action... that's will map to status
   </c:if>
   <c:otherwise>
     <p:outputLabel value=#{varTable[column.property]}/>
   </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

but all cases were `<c:otherwise>`. i'm fixed with remove property `status` and add new column status in the last. but with more columns, i need compare that still using `columns`. please help me!

Comment: Just use conditionally rendering... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385278/conditional-rendering-in-jsf Nothing PrimeFaces, datatable or multiple columns related

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional rendering in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385278/conditional-rendering-in-jsf)

Comment: i think, render using for show or not show this component in browser. it's same `if(check?) show or hide`. in my case, i want to check more (role and more..), then show more component

Comment: Then add the conditions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870462/conditionally-displaying-jsf-components